# Using 3rd party script in html

Tags: javascript, html

So actually i am not much familiar with javascript that's why i am going to post it to know something that i am going to know,

So here it is,

Suppose i have html page and hosted on some where on internet and its coding is,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......</p>
The <a href="http://sitelink.com">link</a> of the document ......
</body>

</html>
```

**In this code Link anchor text use for hyperlink, I would like to use javascript that call from another site, where the link exist and it display over there like this.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/java.js">
```

***I want to know that what code i put on java.js so it show the hyperlink in my html file and how and where do i add code to html page and in javascript***

Advance Thanks for help  :)

Comment: if you are trying to load other links in your site without leaving the page, then you looking for AJAX loading

Comment: @MichaelB would you like to tell me how to do that, i need complete coding for that, thankyou

Comment: Try this http://www.dzone.com/snippets/converting-links-ajax-links

Comment: Well in this link there is only 1 code which is added to html but not display the code of javascript ....?

Comment: I don't get what your trying to do?

Comment: ok in simple words ...  i need to put hyperlink in html which is hosted on 3rdparty site not on the html page, that's it ..? can u help me out .... ?/???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35243/discussion-between-amir-and-michael-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies in advance if I misunderstood your question, but it sounds like you'd like to use JavaScript from another location on your site.

Using the example above, here's what that would look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        The content of the document......</p>
        The <a href="http://sitelink.com">link</a> of the document ......

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/java.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

You could also link to it in the `<head>` instead, but it's better for performance if the scripts are placed in the footer.

Comment: Thank you but the ahref tag that used in the html code i want this in javascript that called from external, what code i put in java.js ???????

Comment: Sorry Amir, but I don't think I understand what it is you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

your anchor:
    href="javascript:linksomething()"
and js:
    function linksomething(){
    window.location.href=url;
    }
is this what you want?

Comment: No,  Its very simple i want to call a link from 3rd party to html page that's it ........ and for that i need both codes on 3rd party code and html code ...